# How to left outer join and insert new data at the same time into a mysql table

Tags: mysql

I want to insert in new data at same time and merged with outer left join values from another table. I have tried by creating the values first and merge by using union for the selection of two columns which is left outer joined to the table. What other ways can I merge left outer join and newly created values into the table?

```
INSERT INTO Dessert(pie, strawberry)
VALUES('chocolate', '5')
UNION
SELECT cream, iceCream, null
FROM Craving
LEFT JOIN Dessert
ON Craving.cream = Dessert.cream AND Craving.iceCream = Dessert.iceCream
```

The table I am trying to create

```
Dessert                             Craving 
cream iceCream pie strawberry       cream iceCream
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to construct a select statement for the new values and union that to a select from the existing data:

```
INSERT INTO Dessert(pie, strawberry)
SELECT 'chocolate' as cream, '5' as iceCream
UNION
SELECT cream, iceCream
FROM Craving LEFT JOIN Dessert
ON Craving.cream = Dessert.cream AND Craving.iceCream = Dessert.iceCream
```

BUT your schema does not make a lot of sense to me.  You have fields in Dessert called pie, strawberry, cream and ice cream?  And you are selecting the fields cream and iceCream but inserting them into pie and strawberry?  And iceCream is a numeric field stored as a string?

It might be helpful if you could share the table structures you have.  You should be able to export the CREATE statements from your mySQL editor.  Also, it would be good if you could share some sample data.

Comment: I am trying to create like a table with two columns from foreign key and create the rest of data for the table. So like cream and iceCream are the foreign keys from another table.

Comment: Because I need insert the two foreign columns from another table and create rest of the data manually as a record.

Comment: Still am not clear on what you are wanting.  You have four columns in the dessert table, but you are only inserting two, so you are just leaving the other two empty?

Comment: I am trying to insert two columns from another table and create the other two columns with normal insert and not from any table. Is it possible?

Comment: Yes, but union is vertical, not horizontal, so the UNION you have there will select 2 columns times X rows.  And you are only specifying two fields in your insert, so you will only be inserting two, and if you did end up with a select that had more than two columns, the insert would fail.

Comment: So if my insert has more than two columns, how should I insert it in with the two foreign key column?

Comment: I am not sure why you are trying to duplicate the external data.  I don't think foreign key is what you mean.  Is there data in the other table that is not included in the desserts table, and in a one to many relationship?  From what you gave it looks like the only columns in that other table are the ones you are calling foreign keys.  Look up foreign key and see if that is really what you mean.

Comment: Sorry, I sort of follow online tutorial about importing in data from other table and didn't realise it is duplication of external data. I will research more on it. Thank you for your guidance.